# Create function template in Mathematica automatically

Tags: function, templates, wolfram-mathematica

My aim is to generate a code. This new code has to include different not known in advance functions. When the notebook gets a new function it should be able to insert appropriate arguments. If I do it manually I can use "Edit ► Make Template" function. The question is: how to do it automatically?

I also know about the **Information** function, but it is not what I need exactly.

Comment: besides my answer below, I suggest you post your MMA related question to the new Mathematica StackExchange http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have to create func::usage messages for each func that you create.

In this way , whenever you type func and press ctrl/cmd-K Mathematica will propose a template.